# Trying to boot from disk image with grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, disk-image

I installed Ubuntu and while fresh, captured the whole drive with the command

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb/image.img
```

then placed it into

> `/boot/images/image.img`

I want [GRUB2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) to boot from this image, as Windows does with "native boot" technology from VHDX. I copied memdisk into `/boot` with

```
cp /usr/lib/syslinux/memdisk /boot/
```

And created the new file `50_memdisk`

> /etc/grub.d/50_memdisk

with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh 
set -e IMAGES=/boot/images .
/usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib 
if test -e /boot/memdisk ; then 
  MEMDISKPATH=$( make_system_path_relative_to_its_root "/boot/memdisk" )
  echo "Found memdisk: $MEMDISKPATH" >&2  find $IMAGES -name "*.img" | sort | while read image; 
  do 
    IMAGEPATH=$( make_system_path_relative_to_its_root "$image" )  
    echo "Found floppy image: $IMAGEPATH" >&2  
    cat << EOF menuentry "Bootable floppy: $(basename $IMAGEPATH | sed s/.img//)" 
    { EOF 
      prepare_grub_to_access_device ${GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT} | sed -e "s/^/\t/" 
      cat << EOF  linux16 $MEMDISKPATH bigraw  initrd16 $IMAGEPATH 
    } EOF 
  done 
fi
```

Then I ran

```
chmod +x /etc/grub.d/50_memdisk && update-grub
```

But GRUB2 shows while the boot process is returning

> out of memory

What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is the right place, and you provided a well detailed question.

Answer (score 0):

The image you generated is too big to fit in RAM so a ramdisk is not viable.